# Why did my question migrate?

Tags: support, migration, specific-question, closed-questions

https://superuser.com/questions/726050/how-can-i-hide-iis-smtp-version-number
Has been moved to SuperUser.

It's been upvoted three times here (security) and afterwards moved to SU.

Can anyone give me reasons why this question has been migrated? I found this community better to place the question. Else it would have been ServerFault but not SuperUser?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is about IIS configuration. Nothing about it is related to security.

Yes, you may think that there is a security benefit in hiding the IIS version number. (But I think you're wrong. Hiding the fact that you're running a vulnerable version doesn't make it less vulnerable.) The question “is there a security benefit in hiding the IIS version number?” would be a security question and on-topic here. But this question merely asks how to change the configuration, it's a pure how-to question that isn't about security. It's squarely off-topic here.

Security.SE has a migration path to Super User, but not Server Fault. Server Fault only wants questions from professional system administrators about enterprise hardware and software; if there is any doubt, they don't want the question. In particular, just because the question is about a server doesn't make it on-topic for Server Fault.

Comment: Thanks for the thumbs up, I get the point now. I've added a new question now with your idea. Thanks!